# SIM800L Network Error While Sending E-Mail

Tags: email, smtp, embedded, sim800, sim800l

I have a SIM-800L module and I am trying to send an email using my various email accounts. I tried using manual serial port AT commands and finally, I got this "Network Error":

```
OK
AT+EMAILTO=30
OK
AT+SMTPSRV="smtp.office365.com",587
OK
AT+SMTPAUTH=1,".............@hotmail.com","password"
OK
AT+SMTPFROM=".............@hotmail.com","name"
OK
AT+SMTPRCPT=0,0,".............@hotmail.com","name"
OK
AT+SMTPSUB="Test"
OK
AT+SMTPBODY=4
DOWNLOAD

OK
AT+SMTPSEND
OK

+SMTPSEND: 61
```

Firstly, I tried with my Gmail account, but some developers say that Gmail uses a secured connection and that might be the problem. Then, I swapped my account to my Hotmail account. Also, I checked if Hotmail provides SMTP protocol and found out that it does. Regardless, I only get the "SMTPSEND: 61" error. If I succeed at this sending email process, I will send emails with attachments like photos, text files, etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions about this error? Or are there any alternative ways to send media files except MMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been experimenting with the SIM800L module and stumbled upon an interesting find that I thought might benefit the community here. It seems that the SIM800L struggles with the SSL/TLS handshake process required by modern email services like Gmail, Hotmail, etc. This essentially means that using these services directly for sending emails through the SIM800L might not be feasible.

However, there's a potential workaround for those who need to send emails for their projects. If you have access to your own SMTP server that doesn't require SSL/TLS encryption (essentially operating on port 25 in an unsecured manner), you can still use the SIM800L to send emails. It's not the ideal scenario given the lack of security, but it might serve well in certain use cases or for testing purposes.